# Bluebird Promise Cancellation

Tags: javascript, promise, future, bluebird

Say I have the following Promise chain:

```
var parentPromise = Promise.resolve()
  .then(function () {
    var condition = false;
    if (condition) {
      return parentPromise.cancel('valid reason');
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(function () {
          var someOtherCondition = true;
          if (someOtherCondition) {
            console.log('inner cancellation');
            return parentPromise.cancel('invalid reason');
          }
        });
    }
  })
  .catch(Promise.CancellationError, function (err) {
    console.log('throwing');
    if (err.message !== 'valid reason') {
      throw err;
    }
  })
  .cancellable();
```

The above never enters the `catch`.

If we swap `condition` to `true`, the inner cancellation is never hit, but the `catch` is still not triggered.

removing the `.cancellable` at the end , and replacing all instances of `parentPromise.cancel()` with explicit `throw new Promise.CancellationError()` "fixes" the problem. What I don't understand is why?

Why was the original approach not working?

I am using bluebird 2.3.11.

Comment: I think you must make the promise cancelable *first*, not last.

Comment: Tomalak is right, you are only making the promise returned by `.catch()` at the end cancellable. Parents cannot inherit cancellability from their children after the fact, but children will inherit cancellability from their parents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cancellable()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellable---promise) creates cancellable promises and only they throw `CancellationError` by default, when `cancel` function is called with out any reason.

In your case, you are making the promise `cancellable` only after attaching the `catch` handler. But the promise is not `cancellable` yet. So, `cancel` function call will not raise `Promise.CancellationError`.

You need to change the structure of the code, like this

```
then(function(..) {
    ...
})
.cancellable()
.catch(Promise.CancellationError, function (err) {
    ...
});
```

**Note:** I would recommend promising with its beautiful `Promise` constructor function. It is similar to the ECMA Script 6 specification.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: When I attempted to introduce the promise with a .cancellable() before my .catch(), the server never starts....

Comment: @AbrahamP Make sure that you remove the `;` after `.cancellable`. If that is not the problem, please show the current code.

Comment: Current Code:
https://github.com/apolishch/bookshelf-soft-delete/blob/master/index.js

for error condition, replace lines 20 and 26 with return parentPromise.cancel() and add a line that just says .cancellable between line 30 and 31.

Comment: @AbrahamP I am really sorry, it would be better if you can come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @AbrahamP here is a simple example of a working cancellation: https://gist.github.com/troygoode/cb82991c71eafa0c7323